# What's the most elegant way to convert requests' response to DRF response in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Consider the following flow:

```
public client ----> DRF API on Service A ------> DRF API on Service B
```

Some of the DRF API on Service A merely proxying to Service B, so in the particular API on Service A looks like this:

```
class SomeServiceAPI(APIView):
    def get(request):
        resp = requests.get('http://service-b.com/api/...')
        return Response(resp.json())
```

While this works on normal status, but it has a few issues:

1. It doesn't proxy the actual status code from service b.
2. Unnecessary round-trip of json serialization within Response()
3. If service b returns a non-json error, service does not return actual error from service b.

The question is, is there a better way to do it? I had a look at [Django Rest Framework Proxy](https://github.com/eofs/django-rest-framework-proxy) project, but I am not entirely sure if it actually suits my use case here.

Comment: Crazy idea, but you could build a Response Adapter. Adapt the response from the request package into a DRF Response.
Does the flow goes in both directions? public expects a response from service B, right?

Comment: No, just single direction, always from A to B.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You can solve the status code part by modifying your `Response`:

   ```
   return Response(resp.json(), status=resp.status_code)
   ```
2. For the second part though, this is the essence of Proxying... (True, sometimes you want to manipulate the request and/or the response in the middleman of the proxy, but what you do is the essence).

*Notes:*

- The [DRF Proxy](https://github.com/eofs/django-rest-framework-proxy) that you are suggesting seems to do the job just
  fine, without the need for you to write a specific view just for the
  roundtrip.
- There exist another tool, [DRF Reverse Proxy](https://github.com/danpoland/drf-reverse-proxy) which is a DRF port of [Django Revproxy](https://github.com/TracyWebTech/django-revproxy) and you may want to consider.

The general idea of both of the above is that you create a URL path specifically to Proxy the path to another API:

**DRF Proxy:**

Add your proxy to `settings.py`:

```
REST_PROXY = {
    'HOST': 'http://service-b.com/api/'
}
```

In `urls.py`:

```
url(
    r'^somewere_in_a/$', 
    ProxyView.as_view(source='somewere_in_b/'), 
    name='a_name'
)
```

**DRF Reverse Proxy:**

Pretty much similar with the above, without the settings part:

```
url(
    r'^(?P<path>.*)$', 
    ProxyView.as_view(upstream='http://service-b.com/api/somewere_in_b/'),
    name='a_name'
)
```

*Opinion:* the [DRF Proxy](https://github.com/eofs/django-rest-framework-proxy) seems more solid...

Comment: I had given a quick try on DRF Reverse Proxy, but I couldn't manage to get it up and running, still quite buggy.

Comment: DRF Proxy seems to be only pointing to a single downstream service, I am not bit reluctant to heavily integrate it if later I have to proxy to other services.

Comment: Then you can use the pass-through you have already implement as a Proxy @JamesLin

Comment: I have created my own wrapper will post up shortly

Comment: Good to know mate :) !

Answer (score 6):

I had a look at both existing packages mentioned in John's answer but they don't seem to perfectly suit in my use case, so I have created a simple wrapper to proxy the requests' response to DRF response.

```
# encoding: utf-8
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from __future__ import absolute_import
from rest_framework.response import Response
from requests.models import Response as RResponse


class InCompatibleError(Exception):
    pass


class DRFResponseWrapper(Response):
    """
    Wraps the requests' response
    """
    def __init__(self, data, *args, **kwargs):
        if not isinstance(data, RResponse):
            raise InCompatibleError

        status = data.status_code
        content_type = data.headers.get('content_type')

        try:
            content = data.json()
        except:
            content = data.content

        super(DRFResponseWrapper, self).__init__(content, status=status, content_type=content_type)
```

And use as below:

```
    resp = requests.get(
        '{}://{}/api/v5/business/'.format(settings.SEARCH_HOST_SCHEMA, settings.SEARCH_HOST),
        params=request.query_params
    )
    return DRFResponseWrapper(resp)
```